Excel VBA to match cell colors and return a value on another cell
I'm a newbie here and in VBA as well. I'm not sure if my question has been answered in another forum but I didn't find any. Here's my problem, in Excel, Column A contains multiple coloured cells from Cell A1 to Cell A30, if I add another column (which is Column B) that has coloured cells as well, I need a VBA code to test each cells like if Cell A1 colour matches Cell B1 colour, then return a text "green" on another column (Cell D1)
I can't seem to do it using conditional formatting, so my hope would be in VBA. Unfortunately, I don't know how


The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

(1) It is usually a bad idea to define values by color. What is red, how is it defined? By RGB? By ColorIndex? By a specific index into your Theme definition? What if you define red by RGB(255, 0, 0) and in your cell you have RGB(240, 0, 0) or RGB(240, 16, 16) - they look the same for the human eye. How do you want to handle colors that look very similar? Which of the following would you consider "Red"?

(2) Conditional formatting cannot access the color of a cell, and it cannot write some text (like "Red") into a cell.
(3) You can write a function in VBA that returns a string (the color name) from a color, but you can't use it as UDF (=User defined function) in a formula. There are some limitations for UDFs, for example it cannot access the color (or other settings) of a cell (I know, there are some dirty tricks around that undergo this limitation, but I will not propagate this).

The function itself could look like this - add any other color you want to handle. However, it doesn't handle colors that look similar - that would be a really tricky task because you would need to define what "similar" means.
Function getColorName(color As Long) As String
    Select Case color
        Case vbRed: getColorName = "Red"
        Case vbWhite: getColorName = "White"
        Case vbBlack: getColorName = "Black"
        Case vbYellow: getColorName = "Yellow"
        Case RGB(0, 175, 80): getColorName = "Green"
        Case RGB(244, 175, 133): getColorName = "Peach"
        Case RGB(166, 166, 166): getColorName = "Grey"
        Case Else
            Dim red As Long, green As Long, blue As Long
            red = color And vbRed
            green = (color And vbGreen) \ &H100
            blue = (color And vbBlue) \ &H10000
            getColorName = "RGB(" & red & "," & green & "," & blue & ")"
    End Select
End Function

And a function that compares two colors:
Function compareColors(color1 As Long, color2 As long) As String
    If color1 = color2 Then
        compareColors = getColorName(color1)
    Else
        compareColors = "No"
    End If
End Function

Now the code to write the color named into column D could look like this:
Sub fillColorNames()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim row As Long
        For row = 1 To 10
            .Cells(row, 4).Value = compareColors(.Cells(row, 1).Interior.color, .Cells(row, 2).Interior.color)
        Next
    End With
End Sub


hmmmm... using RGB value is a good idea! so VBA needs a "specific" instruction... yeah! RGB values is a good way to go to identify what is "red" from another shade of red
